Filter for supply voltage of amplifiers
I need to design an ultra low noise amplifier in transimpedance architecture. This is the architecture I have chosen:

In addition to the decoupling capacitors on the supply pin I have also added two 470 uF capacitors for each power rail:
https://www.digikey.bg/en/products/detail/nichicon/PCR1C471MCL1GS/4694609

I noticed when I supply the circuit with normal power supplies, I get about 0.11mV noise on the output of the amplifiers when there is no signal in the output:

When testing the circuit with a battery, I observed significantly lower noise levels. This leads me to consider adding filtering to the power supply to reduce noise on the supply pin, even when using an external power supply. Could you please advise on the appropriate type of filtering to implement for the supply pin?

Yes, use some R-C (or L-C) filtering on power supplies.
You should use a circuit like this one.
Be sure that the ground should be as nearest the supplies pins (possibly "between").
Sometimes, the resistor should be replaced by an inductor.

